# Keeping major navigation sticky

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior

keeping important navigation sticky and table scrollable.

what will  be easier for user 
1) To keep the important CTA sticky below the table, or

2) On the top of the table will be more visible.[image]

Comment: Your question is low quality. Please give some information regarding the context and upload a good quality screenshot.

Comment: Are the CTA always in the same place? Have you tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the normal reading pattern is from left to right and top to the bottom and also my first need as a user would be "first to understand the data" and then to decide what to do, so for me the buttons on bottom seems more clear